# Can I see iOS Unity debug logs on windows?

Tags: c#, ios, windows, unity-game-engine, mobile

So I need to debug my unity app but I dont have a macbook with xcode to get the logs. Is there any way I can get debug Logs from my iphone on windows ? would using a virtual machine running macOS work ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean , may take a look here .https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJUcBQ07jSc&t=268s&ab_channel=GeraldVersluis

Answer (score 0):

I never tried a virtual machine for my ios build but maybe this solution will suit you:
Check this case when you build and all logs appear on your Iphone.

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Realtime Log functionality from the 3utools app: http://www.3u.com/tutorial/articles/146/how-to-view-the-realtime-log-of-your-idevice-using-3utools

Answer (score 0):

I tried 3utools from above, and it did work!
So far, I haven't seen a way to filter the log, so it's a lot of text to deal with... but better than nothing!

You'll need to enabled development mode on your iphone (Privacy & Security -> Development Mode), and then go to 3utools -> Toolbox -> Realtime Log.